# Can I print things into the console in Vue getter?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, getter

I am new to vue, debugging something, and have question: can I print something into the console from Vue getter? For example:

```
get foo() {
  console.log(bar);
  return bar;
}
```

Can I write that line `console.log(bar)`?

Thanks!

Comment: If that was the answer you needed could you please respond with answered :) thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can I write that line `console.log(bar)`?

To answer you question specifically, yes you can do that (assuming `bar` is declared within scope).

Did you declare that getter on the Vue instance? If so, that is unusual, and typically you would use a [computed property](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html) instead.

Using `console.log()` as a quick debugging mechanism is fine, but like [Wally suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62544797/734040) you should use the Vue dev tools extension for most debugging situations, also in combination with the JavaScript debugger built into your browser.

Answer (score 2):

Best thing to do for debgging vue is to download the extension for vue.js - its the debugging tool chosen by vue -

(I'm assuming chrome is being used so the link below is for the debugger) -

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vuejs-devtools/nhdogjmejiglipccpnnnanhbledajbpd?hl=en

Using the debugger you can access the vue instance which is what I think that is what your looking for here:

[image]

hope that helps -
W

Comment: Hi Wally thanks for your response. I have the vue debugger but I have to navigate the code not the DOM so I have to print out things. Do you know if i `console.log()` works inside a Vue getter by any chance?